# Jquery UI Dialog button gets executed without clicking

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am calling the Jquery UI Dialog from the success function of an ajax call. The code for the Dialog is like this -

```
    $.ajax({
          'url': "../../controller/myclass.cfc",
          'data':{
              method: "generateQuote",
              'quoteItems':quoteItems,
              returnFormat: "json"
          },
          success: function(data){
             $("#place_of_loading_image").hide();
             newQuoteId = data.toString();

               //New Quote Confirmation popup
                 $( "#newQuoteAddedAlert" ).dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    resize: 'auto',
                    width: 'auto',
                    modal: true,
                    closeOnEscape: false,
                    closeText: "Close" ,
                    position: "center top",
                    buttons: [{
                        text:"Continue", click: function(){
                            $("#newQuoteAddedAlert").dialog("close");
                        }},
                        {text:"Finish",click: function(){   
                            $("#newQuoteAddedAlert").dialog("close");
                            //alert("shutup");
                            location.reload(); 
                        }
                    }]

                });


             //showConfirmationAlert(newQuoteId);

          },error: function( objRequest, strError ){
        }
     });
```

My Problem is that the `location.reload()` inside the Finish Button Function gets called as soon the dialog loads. I want it to only get executed once the user has clicked the Finish Button.

What wrong am I doing?

Comment: seems fine to me http://plnkr.co/edit/coWHsZZBshLDURgaItqU?p=preview

Comment: I see what you have done there. You are calling it from a button click. But I cannot call it like that. Mine gets called from inside of a success function of AJAX call.

Comment: can you share the code which opens the dialog

Comment: I have edited the question. The dialog is called inside the success of the ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to define dialog in $(document).ready block instead of in success method? In that case you just need to open your dialog in success method like this:

```
$( "#newQuoteAddedAlert" ).dialog('open');
```

Comment: I did that and it still calls the reload function inside the button function. I just want it to be not called on page load

Comment: Can you try with this: if($("#newQuoteAddedAlert").dialog( "isOpen" )){
     window.location.reload();
     }

Comment: That did not work. But It gave me an idea of putting a flag there which makes sense and fixes the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same weird issue.  I didn't investigate much, but it started occurring when I changed

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()" />
```

to:

```
<button onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
```

so I simply switched it back.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar kind of problem.The reason being : dialog code was copied  from old page having jQuery v-1.7 & older jQuery-ui.js and the new page had jQuery-3.3.1 but older jQuery-ui.js.

So use both above scripts with **latest versions**.